# Gimp (Scheme) How do you return a variable from a script?

Tags: scheme, layer, gimp

Seems like a simple thing but I haven't found an answer.

Custom script. How do you return a variable?

Specifically, I want to return **copiedLayer**.

```
(define (script-copy-first-layer inImg)
    (let* 
        ( 
            (layers       (cadr (gimp-image-get-layers inImg) ) )
            (numLayers    (car (gimp-image-get-layers inImg) ) )
            (layer        (aref layers 0))

            (copiedLayer (car (gimp-layer-copy layer TRUE)))
        )

        (gimp-image-add-layer inImg copiedLayer 0)
        (gimp-layer-set-visible copiedLayer TRUE)

        (gimp-layer-set-lock-alpha copiedLayer TRUE)
        (gimp-layer-add-alpha copiedLayer)      
    )
)

(script-fu-register
    "script-copy-first-layer"
    "<Image>/Image/Copy First Layer"
    "Copy First Layer"
    "Black Orchid Studios"
    "Black Orchid Studios"
    "July 2017"
    "RGB*, GRAY*"
    SF-IMAGE    "Image" 0
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add `copiedLayer` to the end of the `let` statement.

I believe this is what you need:

```
(define (script-copy-first-layer inImg)
    (let* 
        ( 
            (layers       (cadr (gimp-image-get-layers inImg) ) )
            (numLayers    (car (gimp-image-get-layers inImg) ) )
            (layer        (aref layers 0))

            (copiedLayer (car (gimp-layer-copy layer TRUE)))
        )

        (gimp-image-add-layer inImg copiedLayer 0)
        (gimp-layer-set-visible copiedLayer TRUE)

        (gimp-layer-set-lock-alpha copiedLayer TRUE)
        (gimp-layer-add-alpha copiedLayer)    

        copiedLayer
    )
)

(script-fu-register
    "script-copy-first-layer"
    "<Image>/Image/Copy First Layer"
    "Copy First Layer"
    "Black Orchid Studios"
    "Black Orchid Studios"
    "July 2017"
    "RGB*, GRAY*"
    SF-IMAGE    "Image" 0
)
```

Comment: Could you show exactly where it goes? There are a couple of places that might be the 'end' of the statement. Also, do I need parentheses around it?

Comment: Edited the answer with that. And no, if you place parentheses around it, I believe the compiler will attempt to call it as a function, which will likely produce an error.

Comment: Thanks!

I can now assign a variable when I use a let statement in another script.

    `(let*
        (
            (layerCopy (script-copy-first-layer image))
        )`

Comment: Great, glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 0):

ScriptFu scripts declare and define PDB procedures in the GIMP Procedural Database.

But you can't declare a return type.  Notice that 'script-fu-register' is declaring.  Unlike in PyGimp, there is no clause for declaring return values.
All PDB procedures (aka plugins) declared in ScriptFu return void.

Considered as just Lisp, scripts DO return the value of the last evaluated expression.  But it doesn't pass through the PDB machinery.  Within the same program text, you can call the defined function 'script-copy-first-layer' and receive a value, but you can't call the corresponding PDB procedure from another script and receive a value.

Strange but true.  There is no good reason why it is so.